# gdb/gfortran broken after 7.2/4.7

Tags: gcc, memory-management, gdb, fortran, gfortran

I have three machine, two run Linux and one run OS X Yosemite with different version of `gfortran` and `gdb`. `gdb` on my old box work well with allocated arrays, however, newer version of `gdb` (after 7.2) and `gfortran` (after 4.7) do not seem to be able to examine the allocatable variables.

My question is: is this an expected behavior or is there a patch to keep `gfortran`, `gdb` work like the older version?

This is a small version of code I tested:

```fortran
integer :: x(2,3)
integer, allocatable :: y(:,:)

allocate(y(2,3))

x = reshape([1,2,3,4,5,6], [2,3], order=[2,1])
y = reshape([1,2,3,4,5,6], [2,3], order=[2,1])

print *, 'x', transpose(x)
print *, 'y', transpose(y)

end
```

And results from three machine

It works well on 4.7 on Fedora 17 (no longer maintained)

```
[qlle@(none) ~]$ gdb --version | head -n1
GNU gdb (GDB) Fedora (7.4.50.20120120-54.fc17)
[qlle@(none) ~]$ gfortran --version | head -n1
GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.7.2 20120921 (Red Hat 4.7.2-2)

(gdb) i lo
x = (( 1, 4) ( 2, 5) ( 3, 6) )
y = (( 1, 4) ( 2, 5) ( 3, 6) )
(gdb) p y(:,2)
$1 = (2, 5)
(gdb) p y(2,:)
$2 = (4, 5, 6)
(gdb) show language 
The current source language is "auto; currently fortran".
```

However, with latest version through `homebrew` on Mac machine, I got `incomplete type` instead.

```
~/Downloads❯ gdb --version | head -n 1
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.8.1

~/Downloads❯ gfortran --version | head -n1
GNU Fortran (Homebrew gcc 4.9.2_1) 4.9.2

~/Downloads❯ gdb a.out
...
(gdb) break 9
Breakpoint 1 at 0x100000b41: file alloc.f90, line 9.
run
...
(gdb) info locals
x = (( 1, 4) ( 2, 5) ( 3, 6) )
y = <incomplete type>
```

And even worse, on other Linux box with 4.8 (Ubuntu 14.04), it seems to point to incorrect section (stack instead of heap):

```
link@hyrule:~$ gdb --version | head -n1
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
link@hyrule:~$ gfortran --version | head -n1
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
(gdb) i lo
x = (( 1, 4) ( 2, 5) ( 3, 6) )
y = (( 0) )
(gdb) p &y
$1 = (PTR TO -> ( integer(kind=4) (*,*))) 0x7fffffffe4f0
(gdb) p &x
$2 = (PTR TO -> ( integer(kind=4) (2,3))) 0x7fffffffe540
(gdb) p *((integer *) y)@6
$6 = (1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6)
```

Comment: This appears to be a bug that should be reported -- perhaps add it to this open bug: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=9395

Comment: Thank you for your reply @casey, actually `gdb` in Fedora (and RHEL) came with a patchset, include VLA http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/gdb.git/, that's why it's the only version can print/examine allocated arrays. I'm trying to patch gdb in OS X the same way but it seems very long...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to answer the question. Actually `gdb` on Fedora come with a patchset http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/gdb.git/ that enable debugging allocatable arrays for Fortran code.

In order to get allocatable arrays working on other platform, we need to rebuild `gdb` from a specific branch like archer-jankratochvil-vla from Archer gdb https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/ProjectArcher.

No need to patch gfortran though.

Comment: Sorry to be unclear, VLA http://intel-gdb.github.io/ or Variable Length Array  help us to examine the heap arrays like the way we do a stack one, instead of `print *((integer *) x)@10`, just `print x` is enough, it much easier to work with multi-dimension arrays...