# debugging gfortran allocatable array with gdb on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, fortran, gdb, gfortran, osx-elcapitan

I am trying to debug a fortran program that makes use of allocatable arrays on `OS X El Capitan (10.11.6)`. The program is compiled with `gfortran` (`GNU Fortran (GCC) 8.1.0`) and I am using `gdb` (`GNU gdb (GDB) 8.1`). Both `gfortran` and `gdb` were built from source (instructions: [gfortran](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2017/05/21/compiling-gcc-macos/), [gdb](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin)). My problem is that `gdb` does not correctly recognise/display allocatable arrays.

This is an [old and known](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=9395) problem, that appears to have been fixed in recent Linux distributions. So I suspect that this is a problem only on `OS X`. Next, I will show a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

## The problem

Test program called test.f90:

```
program ex
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.d0)
  integer :: i
  real(kind=dp),allocatable :: tab(:)
  real(kind=dp) :: tab2(10)
  allocate(tab(1:10))
  do i=1,10
     tab(i)=real(i,kind=dp)
     tab2(i)=tab(i)
  end do
  write(*, '(*(f3.0,1x))') tab
  write(*, '(*(f3.0,1x))') tab2
end program ex
```

Compiled using:

```
gfortran -g test.f90 -o test
```

Calling `gdb` on the executable:

```
gdb ./test
(gdb) b test.f90:12
(gdb) run
(gdb) info locals
i = 11
tab = ()
tab2 = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
(gdb) p &tab
$1 = (PTR TO -> ( real(kind=8) (*))) 0x7fff5fbff930
(gdb) p &tab2
$2 = (PTR TO -> ( real(kind=8) (10))) 0x7fff5fbff8e0
```

Note that the size of the allocatable variable `tab` is not printed/recognised correctly in gdb.

## Expected result

On an Ubuntu virtual machine with `gdb` (`GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.0.1-0ubuntu1) 8.0.1`), and `gfortran` (`GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2) 7.2.0`), compiling and debugging using the same commands as above, gives the *expected* result:

```
(gdb) info locals
i = 11
tab = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
tab2 = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
(gdb) p &tab
$1 = (PTR TO -> ( real(kind=8) (10))) 0x55555575a240
(gdb) p &tab2
$2 = (PTR TO -> ( real(kind=8) (10))) 0x7fffffffd7f0
```

Thus on `Ubuntu`, `gdb` correctly reports the size and content of the allocatable array `tab` identical to `tab2`. On both `Ubuntu` and `OS X` the actual program output is the same and as expected, namely:

```
./test
1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9. 10.
1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9. 10.
```

## What I have tried

There are a number of related questions already on this site, but none that I can find offer a working solution (on a more *recent* `OS X` version like `El Capitan`). Previous suggestions have been:

- [using `lldb`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32752060), although others, myself included, finds that this [does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44988718).
- a [workaround using pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30076354), e.g.: `(gdb) print *((real_8 *) tab)@10`, to view 10 element of allocatable array `tab` (I would really like to avoid this as it becomes complicated for all but the simplest cases)
- [installing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28089127) the `jankratochvil-vla` branch from [GDB Project Archer](http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/ProjectArcher)

I can find no example of a working build of the Project Archer `gdb` branch on a recent version of `OS X`. And my own efforts to build the *Project Archer* branch still results in a `gdb` that does not print out the allocatable array correctly.

It seems as if `gdb` installed from e.g. `homebrew` [also has this problem](http://rulonder.github.io/2016/05/04/fortran-debug-in-visual-studio-code/). Therefore, if anyone can give me some advice on how to obtain or build a version of `gdb` on `OS X El Capitan` (or newer `MacOS` if need be) that can print allocatable arrays from `gfortran`, I would truly appreciate it. Alternatively, any explanation as to why it is not possible would also be helpful.

Comment: Please use the [tag:fortran] tag for all Fortran questions.

Comment: @VladimirF sorry about that, just edited my question to also include the flag (I've been too broad with flags in the past, so tried to be very specific this time)

Comment: Why would you expect the result that you have shown? These arrays are uninitialized so they can contain anything at that particular step in the debugger. On Arch Linux gfortran v8.1.0 I get `$1 = (1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.3477776834029696e-322, 1.6391144015104463e+59, 3.4584595208887258e-323, 1.6391141290730679e+59)`.

Comment: @RaulLaasner, bad example perhaps, the problem is not the uninitialised entries, but the first entry in the array. I just showed debug results after one iteration, so `tab(1)` should be the same as `tab2(1) = 1`. If you run through all iterations, they should both read `(1, 2, ..., 8, 9, 10)`, but this does not happen for `tab`

Comment: So to be specific, on linux it seems to work as expected, while on OS X, the allocatable array `tab` is not recognised/displayed correctly

Comment: The problem is almost certainly caused by Apple rejecting anything with the GPLv4 license and just hating GPL in general. Did you try building GDB from official sources?

Comment: @VladimirF, I've largely given up getting this to work. My last effort (some time ago!) was building gdb 8.1 from official sources, but that did not resolve this issue - while the same version of gdb worked perfectly fine on Linux. At that time, installing using homebrew also had the same problem.