# How to print allocatable fortran int64 array in GDB

Tags: fortran, gdb, gfortran

I know I can print the `n+1`-th element of a normal integer array `data` in GDB as

```
print *((integer *)data + n)
```

But how can I correctly print the element out if `data` is an `integer(INT64)` allocatable array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: some older GDB versions or branches used in some unfortunate OSs or distributions may fail to support the allocatable arrays correctly. In that case use the C syntax.

If `int64_t` isn't recognized by an old GDB, use `long` or whatever old C type corresponds to a 64-bit integer.

---

You can really just do

```
 print data(n+1)
```

Using

```
 print *((integer *)data + n)
```

is C mode GDB syntax, but in Fortran mode it is really simple.

If you really want the complicated C syntax, you can use it even in Fortran mode, it is

```
 print *((int64_t *)(&data) + n)
```

In C mode (after `set langauge c`), you can also use

```
print *((int64_t *)data + n)
```

this one does not work in Fortran mode (`Cannot access memory at address 0x29`).

---

Example:

```
use iso_fortran_env

integer(int64), allocatable :: data(:)

integer :: n

data = [(i, i=1, 100)]

n = 5

continue

end
```

gdb:

```
GNU gdb (GDB; openSUSE Leap 15.1) 8.3.1
...
(gdb) break int64.f90:9
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4005ec: file int64.f90, line 9.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/lada/f/testy/stackoverflow/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, MAIN__ () at int64.f90:9
9       n = 5
Missing separate debuginfos, use: zypper install libgcc_s1-gcc10-debuginfo-10.1.1+git68-lp151.27.1.x86_64 libquadmath0-gcc10-debuginfo-10.1.1+git68-lp151.27.1.x86_64
(gdb) step
13      end
(gdb) print data(n+1)
$1 = 6
(gdb) print *((int64_t *)(&data) + n)
$2 = 6
(gdb) set language c
Warning: the current language does not match this frame.
(gdb) print *((int64_t *)data + n)
$3 = 6
(gdb) print *((long *)data + n)
$4 = 6
```

Comment: Unfortunately, ` print data(n+1)` does not work for me and I got `No symbol "int64_t" in current context.` when trying to use the C pointer method. I'm using `gdb (GDB) 8.0.1` on Mac OS X, not sure whether it is a version problem.

Comment: @KevinPowell Yes, it is very likely a version problem, please see my note at the very bottom of my answer. If your GDB is that old that it even doesn't understand `int64_t`, use just `long`. Or something else if `long` does not correspond to 64 bits in your system. But it normally should.

Comment: Also make sure you are in the Fortran mode (it should be automatic, but you can try `set language fortran`). Or in C mode when trying those commands I showed for C mode.

Comment: @KevinPowell See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50469327/debugging-gfortran-allocatable-array-with-gdb-on-mac-os-x Apple hates GPLv4 and will not provide any new software version that uses this license. If you want a new version, you have to look elsewhere or compile from original source. Otherwise you have to keep using old methods.

Comment: After setting `set language c`, `print *((long *)data + 1)` does not bother with `long` any more but gives wrong result. I just installed `gdb` on `CentOS 7` and everything works perfectly as you have shown. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @VladimirF GPLv**4**?